# How to replace a pattern matched string in Python?

Tags: python, regex, replace

Say I have a lines that read as..

```
Bob: Owns(Car, v_bmw)
John: Buying(Bike, v_harleydavidson)
```

Desired output is..

```
Bob: Owns(Car, _)
John: Buying(Bike, _)
```

I tried as below..

```
line = "Bob: Owns(Car, v_bmw)
new_line = line.replace('%v_%','_)',1)
```

Comment: Please post what you're tried, and what's not working about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `re.sub`

```
>>> import re
>>> s = '''Bob: Owns(Car, v_bmw)
John: Buying(Bike, v_harleydavidson) '''
>>> print re.sub(r'v_\w*', '_', s)
Bob: Owns(Car, _)
John: Buying(Bike, _) 
>>>
```

`\w*` should match zero or more word characters. You may also use `\w+` which matches one or more word characters.